# Dynamic query and caching

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have two problem sets. What I am preferably looking for is a solution which combines both.

Problem 1: I have a table of lets say 20 rows. I am reading 150,000 rows from other table (say table 2). For each row read from table 2, I have to match it with a specific row of table 1 (not matching whole row, few columns. like if table2.col1 = table1.col && table2.col2 = table1.col2) etc. Is there a way that i can cache table 1 so that i don't have to query it again and again ?

Problem 2: I want to generate query string dynamically i.e., if parameter 2 is null then don't put it in where clause. Now the only option left is to use immidiate execute which will be very slow.

Now what i am asking that how can i have dynamic query to compare it with table 1 ? any ideas ?

Comment: You're thinking too much. You should let the database and the OS and the filesystem do this for you. It's what they're designed to do so anything you come up with will be far inferior. Everything cache's... let it do so.

Comment: hmm, so the small table will automatically be cached by oracle ?

Comment: Yes @EmAe, it will be. It depends on how much is going on in the database of course, but Oracle will do a fair amount of caching for you. Just try running the same query twice. The second time will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 1, as mentioned in the comments, let the database handle it. That's what it does really well. If it is something being hit often, then the blocks for the table should remain in the database buffer cache if the buffer cache is sized appropriately. Part of DBA tuning would be to identify appropriate sizing, pinning tables into the "keep" pool, etc. But probably not something that needs worrying over.

If the desire is just to simplify writing the queries rather than performance, then views or stored procs can simplify the repetitive use of the join.

For problem 2, a query in a format like this might work for you:

```
SELECT id, val
  FROM myTable
  WHERE filter = COALESCE(v_filter, filter)
```

If the input parameter `v_filter` is null, then just automatically match the existing column. This assumes the existing filter column itself is never null (since you can't use `=` for null comparisons). Also, it assumes that there are other indexed portions in the `WHERE` clause since a function like `COALESCE` isn't going to be able to take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1 you just join the tables. If there is an equijoin and one table is quite small and the other large then you're likely to get a hash join. This is effectively a caching mechanism, and the total cost of reading the tables and performing the join is only very slightly higher than that of reading the tables (as long as the hash table fits in memory).

It does not make a difference if the query is constructed and run through execute immediate -- the RDBMS hash join will still act as an effective cache.

Comment: say i want to do a select statement. i.e., `select * from table 2 where col1 = col1_val and col2 = col2_val` ... now there are chances taht col2_val is null so there is no point adding it here, so i want to `select * from table1 where col1 = col1_val` i.e., its a dynamic query. which can be executed by `execute immediate` command